# Postman is changing my body from application/json to string

Tags: json, rest, aws-lambda, postman, aws-api-gateway

I'm having an architecture that looks like that on AWS, if it matters to the issue:
 Lambda function - API Gateway

I'm testing my API with postman by calling my API with a raw body of application/json type.

[image]

But in my lambda, the body looks like this

```
body: '{
      \n\t"name": "Coinche",
      \n\t"description": "Un jeu intéressant à plusieurs",
      \n\t"rules": "Gagner",
      \n\t"origin": "France"\n
}'
```

which gives me an error, obviously.

So what's the catch here? Doesn't the application/json takes care of sending a json? Should I translate the string back to json inside lambda function?

Comment: Try JSON.parse(body), if you're using javascript. That would turn the string into JSON.

Comment: I'll try, I'm wondering if it's normal behavior for my raw body to become a string.

Comment: did you add `content-type:application/json` in postman's request header?

Comment: Yes it's added by default by postman when changing the type of the raw body.

Comment: Still, it worked by doing the JSON.parse(event.body).

Comment: "I'm wondering if it's normal behavior for my raw body to become a string." For it to be transmitted over http, it is serialized into a string. From there, the Content-Type headers tell your server how to interpret that string. Some libraries take the liberty of parsing that into JSON for you, but some leave it up to you.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may require to add Content-Type: application/json on API Gateway Integration Request body template mapping like this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Where can I find this menu? I looked in APIs/myAPI/settings already.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste, settings are required to set for individual functions (GET/POST etc.) in your API. I have added one more image to point where to find these settings.

Comment: Thanks for the new screenshot!

Answer (score 1):

*This is not exactly an answer to the question*, but for me, none of this resolved the issues of getting `\n\t` added to my JSON.  JSON.parse and JSON.stringify all failed with this and I could not get past the errors being thrown.

I switched from using Postman to [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) and problem went away.  I also noticed it uses [end-to-end encryption](https://support.insomnia.rest/article/57-encryption) so I'm not trying to bother with variables in the same way for my keys etc..

I just have a JSON file with all my variables to re-use in Insomnia.  Works pretty nicely so far.

I'm not trying to sell anything here, it is just that it took me a while to even figure out what was going on and that the issue was coming from Postman, so it seemed worth sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same experience but in a different environment.
Under the same server program from desktop windows 10 and mac, postman with windows 10 worked and the one with mac didn't work like yours.

The key "Content-Type" in Headers (refer to the below image) were both unchecked, but once I checked it on mac, it just became normal.

[postman menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMdYI.png)